# Structuring the enabling and arranging of "pages" in my database

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-structures, structure

I have 0-30 pages that a user can either `enable or disable` and also `re-arrange` if enabled.

Each page has a table in the database with specific variables that go along with it that displays information.

On my website I have a section where it displays all the enabled pages in the order that they are in (much like a word document)

I am having trouble figuring out an appropriate way to structure my database that lets me know what pages are enabled and, if they are enabled, what order they are in.

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Are the pages themselves contained in the database, or are you just trying to keep track of references to the page names (or file names)?

Comment: Each page has a table in the database with specific variables that go along with it that displays information. I then display the enabled pages in the order they are declared much like a word doc @EmmyS

Comment: each page has a table?? really??

Comment: @redreggae Each page is a `form` that stores information, so yes.

Comment: and why not just make fields `enabled tinyint` and `sort tinyint`?

Comment: @redreggae that doesn't seem like the smartest way. That would be 60 different fields. And not "all" pages will have it's on table (sorry). Some just display information.

Comment: I think the smartest way would be one table for pages and a foreign table for the information.

Comment: To be clear: you require that each user have the ability to have their own sort and enable settings correct?  Also, please tell us the name of your users table and the name of your pages table (edit into the question).

Comment: That is correct. You can assume the table names are `users` and `pages`

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of the following:

TABLE `page`

```
id_page
pagename
enabled
sort
```

TABLE `field`

```
id_field
fieldname
```

TABLE `page_field`

```
fi_page
fi_field
value
```

This principle is called [Entity–attribute–value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Another way would be to use supertype/subtype model:

TABLE `page`

```
id_page
pagename
enabled
sort
commonfield1
commonfield2
```

TABLE `subpage1`

```
id_subpage1
fi_page
subpage1_specialfield
```

TABLE `subpage2`

```
id_subpage2
fi_page
subpage2_specialfield
```

Supertype/subtype design comes close to your design because each page has an extra table. But you have one supertable `page` where the common fields can be saved.

Answer (score 0):

TABLE pages (your page contents go here)

```
id_page
other...
```

TABLE users (all your user info goes here)

```
user_id
others...
```

TABLE users_pages (your "join" table, relates pages to users).  Every user would have as many rows as there are pages.  So your total number of rows is number of users X number of pages.  This could be quite large!  Should still be fast if you set up your indexes properly.

```
user_id
page_id
disabled
rank
```

The simpler case: SELECT the pages enabled for user '7':

```
SELECT page_id
FROM pages p
LEFT JOIN users_pages up 
ON p.page_id = up.page_id 
WHERE up.disabled != TRUE AND up.user_id = 7;
```

SELECT the pages enabled for user '7' in order:

```
SELECT page_id
FROM pages p
LEFT JOIN users_pages up 
ON p.page_id = up.page_id 
WHERE up.disabled != TRUE
AND up.user_id = 7
ORDER BY up.rank desc;
```

This solution does not currently handle the circumstance where a user has not specified an order for the pages.  Nor does it handle the circumstance where a new page is added after a user has specified an order.  You will want to handle those circumstances and you can with this structure.